# Why does my really really simple Java program which doesn't yet do anything sometimes work and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jcombobox

I'm just starting out in Java, and only ever used PHP before - finding it hard to get my head round the object-orientated thing. I am using the Eclipse IDE.

I am trying to make a program that will tell you your weight on another planet - seems simple enough

All I have done so far is make half the interface in Swing (is that what it's called?)

Sometimes I run it, and it comes up as I would expect, with the title, textboxes etc....
other times (when absolutely no changes have been made), it just comes up with a blank screen
[image]

The image shows what it looks like when it is working. When it's not working, there are just no objects. It works about 20% of the time.

**I think this might have been because of my drop  down menu - or JComboBox, this has been such a head ache - Eclipse made me add "< Object>" after each mention of JComboBox - it said "JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized"**

I have no idea why this is, and I'm probably just being really thick, sorry if this is a stupid question, but how can I fix this problem, what's wrong with my code?

```
package calc;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class View extends JFrame {

static String titleText = "Calculate your Mass on another Plannet";

public View(){
    super(titleText);
    setSize(500,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);

    JPanel inputData = new JPanel();


    //Labels
    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel (titleText, JLabel.CENTER);
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    JLabel lblInputMass = new JLabel ("Weight", JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel lblInputUnits = new JLabel("Units");     


    //Input Boxes and Lists
    JTextField txtInputMass = new JTextField(5);

    JComboBox<Object> comInputUnits;
    String arrUnits[] = {"Kilos", "Stone", "Pounds"};
    comInputUnits = new JComboBox<Object>(arrUnits);
    comInputUnits.setSelectedIndex(1);


    //Buttons
    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    //Append objects
    add(lblTitle);
    inputData.add(lblInputMass);
    inputData.add(txtInputMass);
    inputData.add(lblInputUnits);
    inputData.add(comInputUnits);
    inputData.add(btnCalculate);

    add(inputData);


}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    View sal = new View();


}

}
```

Sorry it's quite a long question, and I'd be so grateful to any suggestions or answers, 
as I said, I know barley anything about Java, and am just starting out  - thank you :)

Comment: IMHO, you should not make so much calls in the constructor. But that might not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see where you add your UI components to any container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should

- only manipulate Swing components inside the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/);
- call `setVisible(true)` only after all the components have been added to the frame;
- spell *Planet* with only one *n*, although that's less important.

The `<Object>` that "Eclipse made you add" are called generic types. Read the [tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, the setVisible(true) at the end fixed it :)

Comment: Which part is the event dispatch thread, I am trying to find out on the internet, but it's not that clear? thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply follow my link, and read the tutorial. It's all explained there.

Comment: lol, I can't understand it :p is the event dispatch thread not just a part of the program like a class? (sorry)

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html to understand what a thread is. And read the second page of the tutorial I linked to to understand what the `main()` method must do.

Comment: Besides @JBNizet point 3. (Plannet -> Planet), also change 'Mass' to 'Weight'.  The mass of an object remains constant even in orbit or free-fall, it is the weight that changes with gravity.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do everything dealing with Swing components inside the EventDispatchThread (EDT).

wrap the call to `new View()` in a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`

Answer (score 2):

Always call `pack()`.  This version works reliably (at least to appear).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class View extends JFrame {

    static String titleText = "Calculate your Weight on another Planet";

    public View(){
        super(titleText);
        // not now!
        //setSize(500,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setVisible(true);

        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);

        JPanel inputData = new JPanel();

        //Labels
        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel (titleText, JLabel.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        JLabel lblInputMass = new JLabel ("Weight", JLabel.LEFT);
        JLabel lblInputUnits = new JLabel("Units");     

        //Input Boxes and Lists
        JTextField txtInputMass = new JTextField(5);

        JComboBox comInputUnits;
        String arrUnits[] = {"Kilos", "Stone", "Pounds"};
        comInputUnits = new JComboBox(arrUnits);
        comInputUnits.setSelectedIndex(1);

        //Buttons
        JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");

        //Append objects
        add(lblTitle);
        inputData.add(lblInputMass);
        inputData.add(txtInputMass);
        inputData.add(lblInputUnits);
        inputData.add(comInputUnits);
        inputData.add(btnCalculate);

        add(inputData);

        // force the container to layout the components.  VERY IMPORTANT!
        pack();
        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is what JB Nizet was alluding to..
        // 'start (or update) the GUI on the EDT'
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new View();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for not using `setLocationByPlatform(true)`, LOL, though still it has my +1, how strange :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw  'Batteries Not Included' with this one, it was a budget job.  If I was going VIP I'd have 1st changed the layout, then dropped the frame 'set size', then...  ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            View sal = new View();
            sal.setSize(500, 400);
            sal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            sal.setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment these lines after the constructor:

```
super(titleText);
setSize(500,400);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried your code with the revisions and It worked all the time :)

Comment: -1. Swing components must be accessed from the EDT. And the above change doesn't change anything.